# How to direct to help page on run time of Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I added a help page to my Web API 2 project following these instructions:
[msdn app help page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/08/enabling-asp-net-web-api-help-pages-for-asp-net-web-forms-applications/)

How on run time do I enable to always display the help page without having to type help in the URL. When I set Index.cshtml as start page I get a 404 error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a route, something like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Help", "", new { area = "Help" }
```

I've not tested this as it's been a long time since I used Help Pages, but it's the way I would do it, or at least try!

Comment: Still got a 404 when I added that to the WebApiConfig.cs, no dice.

Comment: Sorry, it was just an idea. You could try a filter maybe?!

Answer (score 0):

Put the word 'help' (no quotes) as the start page.